# "Unable to split the file provided into multiple, consistent columns" after beginning training using ML.NET

Tags: ml.net

I am using ML.NET for machine learning.

Originally, I used a CSV file and got this error. However I get the same issue when I connect to a database table I set up with the same data. The data is text of varying length and content, I want to generate new text based on this.

I only have one column set up with my text, so I do not understand what this is trying to do nor why it's not working. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
Inferring Columns ...
An Error occured during inferring columns
Unable to split the file provided into multiple, consistent columns.
Microsoft.ML.AutoML.InferenceException: Unable to split the file provided into multiple, consistent columns.
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.ColumnInferenceApi.InferSplit(MLContext context, TextFileSample sample, Nullable`1 separatorChar, Nullable`1 allowQuotedStrings, Nullable`1 supportSparse)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.ColumnInferenceApi.InferColumns(MLContext context, String path, ColumnInformation columnInfo, Nullable`1 separatorChar, Nullable`1 allowQuotedStrings, Nullable`1 supportSparse, Boolean trimWhitespace, Boolean groupColumns)
   at Microsoft.ML.CLI.CodeGenerator.AutoMLEngine.InferColumns(MLContext context, ColumnInformation columnInformation)
   at Microsoft.ML.CLI.Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__0(NewCommandSettings options)
   at Microsoft.ML.CLI.CodeGenerator.CodeGenerationHelper.GenerateCode()
Please see the log file for more info.
Exiting ...
```

Comment: what are you doing to get the error? Loading data? Are you using the default separator while the separator for your data is different?

Answer (score 2):

When this error happened to me I couldn't find much on it. What I did was export my sql database to csv and looked at the data. There were some string descriptions that had newlines and html in them. I cleaned the strings up with some c# and the file loaded and worked great.

If I were you I would inspect your data in csv and look for formatting errors then fix those and retry.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the carriage returns and line forwards, replacing them with an empty string on your SQL table.

I just created a new version of the table, removing these on the offending column, using:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([FIELD_NAME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')
```

Error message is really vague (got the exact one you did) but the above worked for me.

Not sure what other special characters the engine won't like, but my dataset must have only contained the carriage returns or line forwards.

Comment: This was a big help; thank you :) I also had to trim tabs (char 9) from my data set.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it really is a CSV file error.
Even with a popular dataset taken from Kaggle and one from Wikipedia I still got that.
So, if this helps somebody, try with a smaller CSV file that you are 100% sure is correct.